# zte 9560 fairly new when powered on goes to FTM screen

Tags: applications, recovery-mode, factory-reset, restore

I have zte 9560 thats 5 months old. I recently deleted facebook and instagram programs because of downloads that happened 3 times weekly. Now I get FTM screen on start up. After trying suggustions from your site I still am having issues with booting , factory reset. Now the phone is off but there is a small white circle light at bottom that stays on. Any suggestions ? Any chance of getting into phone from laptop ?

Comment: You should flash the firmware

Answer (score 0):

Things to know about factory mode: In many devices, especially the mediatek based ones have three types of booting behaviours.

1. Fastboot(Bootloader)
2. Normal Boot(Starting Android System)
3. Recovery Mode(Updating and Debugging)
4. Factory Mode(Testing the System Hardware)

The automatic booting is Starting Up Android System when phone OS is in good state. Sometimes this partition that might get damaged leading to frequent or infrequent start-up to recovery or basically any other boot automatically. This is just corruption of the Boot Order or Choice.

For booting to recovery problem, this can be fixed by flashing boot.img to recovery partition if one ever wants to use the system without reflashing. This is possible since all these partitions carry bootable images.

Factory mode isn't initiated by an image. It is initiated by a file at `/system/bin/factory`. This is a binary file. Since there's no other way of booting the system using a binary file, this is the hardest brick in Android. The only binary that can replace this is the reboot binary, but though since the Android is not booted up, you can't replace it or flash it in at device off state.

Though one type of boot that we haven't talked about from above is our only last hope. Fastboot Mode. This is initiated almost immediately from boot. While starting the phone, hold the volume up button. This may take you there straight or take you to a menu of options on the type of boot you need to perform.

You'll be lucky if you had allowed OEM unlock from Development Settings while phone was on and working. Here you can boot a recovery like TWRP from there and delete the factory file at bin making it have option to always boot again.

The key combo to boot to fastboot varies from device to device. So you'll have to search for that specific phone model combo.

Note. *Factory Mode is delicate. You have no option other than flashing phone if this was touched from Factory Mode. 'Clear EMMC' is an option that is written as I have written hereon or some chinese characters preceding EMMC. This clears the entire phone Flash including the system, boot, recovery, frp, nvram, logo etc leaving only preloader for loading files to system flash again using Flashing Software*.

**If you incase touched that at Factory Mode just Reflash. Search on how to flash your specific phone model. Good Luck**